# javascript/jquery: Focusing next textarea (not input field) in a form when tab is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, tabs, jquery-selectors

All my inputs in my form are `textarea` with class `large`.

I'm trying the following but it doesn't work:

```
if(e.which == 9){ // tab
    $(this).next('textarea.large').focus();
}
```

I tried 
`$next = $(":textarea:eq(" + ($(":textarea").index(this) + 1) + ")"); $next.focus();`
to no avail (:textarea was not a valid pseudo-element), and a few other variations.

I've also tried this:

```
$(this).next(':input').focus();
```

I have  checked other code here on SO but it seems to be focused on `input type='text'`, and doesn't seem to work with my textareas.

Is there no simple straightforward, cross-browser compatible way to grab all the textareas in my form and just go to the next one? Some of these textareas will have been **dynamically created**, so they won't all be there the first time the page is loaded. But tab needs to work for all of them.

### Edit

This is easily solved in a simple fiddle, but the thing is, I have a few other things happening in the following conditions and events:

```
jQuery(document).on('keydown blur','textarea.large',function(
 if (e.which == 13 || e.type=='focusout' || e.type=='blur' || e.which == 32) //32 is space
 { ... a bunch of stuff on the page, which naturally takes focus out of the current input
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you create and post a fiddle for this?

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar problem using next() to select next textarea closest to the edit button. When edit image click take text put in dialog popup with CKEDITOR with text taken from textarea.

html structure:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src='edit.png' class='edit_comments' />
        <br />
        <textarea>blah blah</textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src='edit.png' class='edit_comments' />
        <br />
        <textarea>blah blah</textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```

this did not work:

```
$( ".edit_comments" ).click(function() {
        var closest_textarea = $(this).next("textarea");
```

this did:

```
$( ".edit_comments" ).click(function() {
        var closest_textarea = $(this).closest("tr").find("textarea");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set tabindex attribute to input and textarea elements.

http://w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp

Comment: I know, but tabIndex doesn't work here because of all the other event listeners on the input fields. I need to explicitly (progrommatically) instruct the cursor to move focus on the next field when tab is pressed.